# How to get put git version into properties file when compiling?

Tags: git, gradle

Using gradle, how to write to a properties file the current git branch so that it gets into the application?

1. build current branch "1.0.0"
2. write to myModule/git.properties with "version=1.0.0" for the file content
3. get tokenised by gradle
4. inside myModule/conf/applicationContext.properties "version=@version@" becomes "version=1.0.0" in final properties file.

Comment: Searching for the title of your question I found [this plugin](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Also this plugin: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version which uses `git describe`